# CardView remove border

Tags: android, kotlin

I want too remove a border on my cardView.
I try set elavation to 0 dp , app:cardPreventCornerOverlap to false and app:cardUseCompatPadding to true , but I can not remove a border from CardView
this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/IMKAWhite"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:elevation="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:background="@color/IMKAWhite"
            android:layout_width="150sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150sp"
                android:layout_height="150sp"
                android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_photo"
                android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bt_edit_profile"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_dp_25"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_16"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_bt_edit"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my screen :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I try doi this :

```
  app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
```

But steal I have a border

Comment: Change to `app:cardElevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 25):

use

`card_view:cardElevation="0dp"` instead of `android:elevation="0dp"`

import the namespace in root element:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

If you're not gonna use elevation and you don't want any border in this layout, just get rid of the `CardView`element and keep the your views in your `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `android:outlineProvider="none"` on your `CardView`/`MaterialCardView`

```xml
com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:outlineProvider="none"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    >

   <!-- Other Views -->

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Material 3

### MDC-Android

Use `app:strokeWidth="0dp"`

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:strokeWidth="0dp">
```

### Jetpack Compose

**It looks like there is no border by default.**

But if you want to add some, use the `border` property of the Card:

```kotlin
Card(
    border = CardDefaults.outlinedCardBorder(),
) {
      // ...
  }
```